# Django caching : reload browser cache when cache is warmed up

Tags: python, ajax, django, angularjs, caching

I am using Angular as front-end and Django as my backend with memcache configured.

The issue I am facing is with AJAX calls angular makes.
Once I use

```
cache.flush_all()
```

and I hit the same url from my browser, the first get request gets acknowledged and new data is sent. But then my app involves sending multiple ajax request to change views. Those views are always being delivered by browser cache.(until I explicitly clear cache or hit Ctrl+R).

I don't want to disable caching entirely, I just want the browser to get the updated cache when older is flushed.

I was trying to use cache_control decorators but with no success.

```
@cache_control(must_revalidate=True)
```

And this is my angular code:

```
$http({method: method, url:url, data:postData }).
          success(...
```

Also note that I am unable to use max_age parameter.As it will discard the new cache too and request will go all the way to process. Instead of that, I need the browser to take the cache which I've already warmedup after flush.

This I was testing with manage.py runserver. The prod environment is gunicorn+nginx. 
Please comment if any extra info is required.

Comment: Why not disable browser-caching altogether using `never_cache` decorator?

Comment: never_cache also seems to disable my server end caching.

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest using `never_cache` decorator. It works by setting response headers to disable caching in the browser as mentioned in the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/cache.py#L132):

```
def add_never_cache_headers(response):
    """
    Adds headers to a response to indicate that a page should never be cached.
    """
    patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=-1)
```